# Can't use html with script in flutter webview

Tags: javascript, flutter, webview, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I had got html code from one site and tried to use it in my flutter webview but nothing happened. When I open file normally from chrome everything lookes good. 
This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://export.otpusk.com/api/session?access_token=***"></script>
<script src="https://export.otpusk.com/js/onsite/"></script>
<script src="https://export.otpusk.com/js/order"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And how I use it:

```
  String filePath = "assets/index.html";
  WebViewController webViewController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("App bar"),),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'about:blank',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webview){
          webViewController = webview;
          _loadHtmlFromAssets();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async{
    String fileHtmlContents = await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
    webViewController.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileHtmlContents,mimeType: 'text/html',encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')).toString());
  }
```

In console I get something like this:

```
I/chromium(13344): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://export.otpusk.com/jsapi/onsite.min.js?_time=20200525, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://export.otpusk.com/js/onsite/ (1)
I/chromium(13344): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://export.otpusk.com/jsapi/onsite.min.js?_time=20200525, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.", source: https://export.otpusk.com/js/onsite/ (1)
I/chromium(13344): [INFO:CONSOLE(24)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.", source: https://export.otpusk.com/jsapi/onsite.min.js?_time=20200525 (24)
```

Please help me, how can I fix this or how can I load just part of website, not all?

Comment: Whatever you have put in the script tag is trying to write into the html document and chrome is trying block it. Please check the documentation of `export.outpusk.com` for the correct way of loading the script file. It specifically tries to insert another script tag into the html page and this is not a secure of loading js files.

Comment: You can try also my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) (which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews) and check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115306/4637638) to a similar issue!