# "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs." Flutter webview

Tags: javascript, flutter, cookies, webview

```
WebView(initialUrl:Uri.dataFromString('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/platform.js"></script>'+<html>Some code</html>,mimeType: 'text/html').toString(), javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,),
```

This CDN is throwing this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs." Flutter webview

Comment: Several things are wrong here and I'm not sure they are related to your issue. Could you provide more context regarding what you're trying to achieve? What is your environment? You should also fix your code because it is not valid. For example, you have HTML tags alongside the first argument of the function you're calling.

Comment: WebView(initialUrl:Uri.dataFromString('hml code here',mimeType: 'text/html').toString(), javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,),                                  actually i want to  use javascript cdn in this html code ....I want to know  how should i use this script cdn in webview ??

Comment: Consider updating your original post. Code in a comment is just not readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

In your case, you can use the `initialData` argument and set your custom HTML through the `InAppWebViewInitialData.data` attribute and set the `InAppWebViewInitialData.baseUrl` to `http://localhost`:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String customHTML = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: """
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>InAppWebViewInitialDataTest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/platform.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        $customHTML
    </body>
</html>
                    """, baseUrl: 'http://localhost'),
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  debuggingEnabled: true,
              )
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
            onLoadStop:(InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you have access to `document.cookie` using JavaScript!

Another way is to put your HTML in an asset file (see the [Load a file inside assets folder](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#load-a-file-inside-assets-folder) Section) and, then, you can use [`InAppLocalhostServer`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#inapplocalhostserver-class) to start a local server to serve your HTML file with your script.